# Sort and display uniq IP's in a file containing lots of different IP's

Tags: bash

I have a file containing lots of lines as following formnat.

The first column would be IP's, and IP could be duplicated. The other columns don't have to be sorted. If the first column just a number I can use "sort -u k1,1".However, in this case, IP has 4 numbers.
Can you please help to sort lines in IP's order, and remove duplicates, only list lines with unique IP's?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What to you want to do? .1 list duplicates, .2 eliminate duplicates, .3 list all ip but uniq...

Comment: Look at the `KEYDEF` section of `man sort`. You can tell `sort` which character ranges to use from any field and that can cover each of the 4-octets of an IP.

Comment: Please, post some sample data with the related expected output.
Don't post them as comments, images, tables or links to off-site
services but use text and include them to your original question. Thanks.

Comment: I added part of the file as an example. I wanted to eliminate duplicates, and list uniq IP's

Answer (score 1):

Lets say your file containing the data is called data.txt, you can do:

```
awk '{print $1}' data.txt | sort | uniq
```

- `awk` keeps only the first column, the IP addresses
- `sort`: sort the IPs
- `uniq`: remove duplicates

If you need to know how many times each IP appears in the file, you can add option `-c` to `uniq`.

Comment: Good start to solution. Only drawback here is `128.59.30.11` sorts before `128.59.30.7`. To fix use the `-V, --version-sort` option to `sort`. Otherwise you will need to sort numerically on each octet.

Comment: There might be cases (i.e 128.59.30.011) where version sort differs https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Version-sort-is-not-the-same-as-numeric-sort.html

Answer (score 1):

This should work sorting each column individually and using number order:

```
awk '{print $1}' file.txt | sort -ut . -k1,1n -k2,2n -k 3,3n -k 4,4n
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming what you want to do is sort based on IP addresses while removing duplicate lines only based on the IP address, below code of sorting and traversing the sorted file to remove duplicates should work:

```
#!/bin/bash
originalFile=/path/to/original/file
outputFile=/path/to/intermediate/file
cleanFile=/path/to/final/file
sort $originalFile > $outputFile
lastIP=""
while read -r line; do
  words=("${line// / }")
  if [ "${words[0]}" != "$lastIP" ]
  then
    printf "%s\n" "$line" >> $cleanFile
  fi
  lastIP="${words[0]}"
done < $outputFile
```